# $ is undefined when loading jQuery through Modernizer.

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I load jQuery with modernizr and all code in the 'complete'-function runs fine! But if I try to call some js from outside 'Moderniz.load' firebug says: '$ is not defined'.

This works:

```
<script>
Modernizr.load([
{
    load: [ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js'],
    complete: function () {
      if ( !window.jQuery ) {
            Modernizr.load('/weblounge-sites/www/js/jquery-1.7.min.js', '/weblounge-sites/www/js/jqueryui-1.8.min.js');
      }
    }
},
{
    load: [ 'some additional scripts' ],
    complete: function() {
        $ = jQuery;
        $(document).ready(function(){
          some js
          });

        });
    }
},  
{
    test: Modernizr.boxshadow,
    nope: 'polyfills/PIE.js',
}
]);
</script>
```

But the call from a view lines later fails:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hauptsponsoren').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', 
        speed: 4000,
        timeout: 10000
    });                 
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am just learning yepnope / Modernizr and I found that if I watch the timing, I am fine.  What I did was add an init() method in your 'complete'.  Then, your $document.ready lines later would be in this init() function.  This worked for me...

Answer (score 5):

Scripts in yepnope/modernizr.load are loaded asynchronously. That means that by design, they won't have executed in the space directly below their inclusion. This makes the page performance better by not blocking the page from rendering further.

The `callback` and `complete` options are there for you to be alerted whenever the scripts are ready. The fastest route to making sure that jQuery exists, is to just wrap the stuff lower on your page:

```
<script>
function appInit() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hauptsponsoren').cycle({
      fx: 'fade', 
      speed: 4000,
      timeout: 10000
    });                 
  });
}
</script>
```

And then in the `complete` function, call the `appInit()` function. Your page load times will thank you.

`complete: function() { ...; appInit(); }`

If your dom is ready at that point, it will run right away, or if it's not yet, it will wait a little longer for that to occur as well.

Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes because your modernizr is loading jQuery and assigning it like this: $ = jQuery, however, it's only assigned within the `complete: function() {` context.
To make it work outside of that context, before your `Modernizer.load` set:

```
var $;
```

That will set the scope of `$` as global so you can use it anywhere at that point.

If you don't set the scope of `$` to global, using jQuery will still work like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
```

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() doesn't work. firebug says: 'jQuery is not defined'.

Comment: See what you get if you try window.jQuery

Comment: Wow, that's really odd.
Open up firebug and watch the "net" panel to see if jQuery is loaded at any point.

Comment: it is loaded from google, status: 200 - that's fine. As I wrote: inside the Modernizer.load I can use jQuery as expected...

Comment: Ok, I would bet the problem is that the modernizer isn't loading jQuery before you're trying to call it. You can test it like this (put this after your modernizer code) `<script type="text/javascript">console.log('page is loaded');</script>`

Then, inside the `complete` method inside the modernizer code, put: `console.log('inside modernizr');`

Now I'm going to bet firebug will show "page is loaded" before it shows "inside modernizr".
Let me know what the result of that is.

Comment: you're right: the code 'inside' modernizr is loaded AFTER everything else. So... the problem is identified - but the solutions cryptically

Comment: At this point, I would do one of two things, I would either put my code inside the "success" callback of modernizer, or I would create a function, something like: `function page_ready()`, which would basically replace the `$(document).ready(function(){` and put my code inside there, then in the modernizer success callback, call page_ready.

I would tend to think option #2 is cleaner, so I would probably go with that one.